# How to get individual datasets of inner join after join when we have few non-join column names same?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, databricks

Hi have data something like below

```
+----+------------+------+-------------------+
|company_id|city    |state     | updated_date|
+----+------------+------+-------------------+
|  111|       city1|    state1 | 1990-12-01|
|  222|       city2|    state2 | 1991-12-01|
+----+------------+------+-----------------+

+----+------------+------+-------------------+
|companyId|city    |state     |    zipcode|
+----+------------+------+-------------------+
|  111|       city1|    state1 | 111111  |
|  222|       city2|    state2 | 222222   |
+----+------------+------+-----------------+
```

I am doing a join on companyId as below

```
Dataset<Row> joinDs = firstDs.join(secondDs,  firstDs.col("company_id").equalTo(secondDs.col("companyId")), "inner");
```

joinDs  has ambiguity columns "city" & "state"

**Questions**

1. how to deal with ambiguity columns? is there any way to distinguish ambiguity columns from joinDs ?
2. how can I select specific columns from joinDs , in which few from "firstDs" and few from "secondDs"?

**Joining static dF to steaming dF/s?**

> When join the static dataframe "secondDs" (from hdfs) with streaming
>   dataframe "firstDs" ( from kafka)  as below

```
 Dataset<Row> joinUpdatedRecordsDs =   firstDs.join(secondDs, firstDs.col("companyId").equalTo(secondDs.col("company_id"), "inner"));
```

It is not giving any results 
  Where are the same is working fine or giving results in spark-batch processing.

What am I doing wrong here ? how to fix this ?

**Error :**

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 385, Column 34: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 385, Column 34: A method named "toString" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$expressions$codegen$CodeGenerator$$doCompile(CodeGenerator.scala:1304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator$$anon$1.load(CodeGenerator.scala:1376)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are two ways to implement this. one is data frame and another one is using  Spark-Sql.

**Dataframe:**

```
var df1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((111,"city1","state1","1990-12-01"),(222,"city2","state2","1991-12-01"))).toDF("company_id","city","state","updated_date")

df1.show
+----------+-----+------+------------+
|company_id| city| state|updated_date|
+----------+-----+------+------------+
|       111|city1|state1|  1990-12-01|
|       222|city2|state2|  1991-12-01|
+----------+-----+------+------------+

var df2 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((111,"city1","state1",111111),(222,"city2","state2",222222))).toDF("company_id","city","state","zipcode")

scala> df1.join(df2,Seq("company_id"),"inner").show
+----------+-----+------+------------+-----+------+-------+
|company_id| city| state|updated_date| city| state|zipcode|
+----------+-----+------+------------+-----+------+-------+
|       111|city1|state1|  1990-12-01|city1|state1| 111111|
|       222|city2|state2|  1991-12-01|city2|state2| 222222|
+----------+-----+------+------------+-----+------+-------+
```

performing inner join using spark select

```
scala> df1.select("company_id","city","updated_date").join(df2.select("company_id","state","zipcode"),Seq("company_id"),"inner").show
+----------+-----+------------+------+-------+
|company_id| city|updated_date| state|zipcode|
+----------+-----+------------+------+-------+
|       111|city1|  1990-12-01|state1| 111111|
|       222|city2|  1991-12-01|state2| 222222|
+----------+-----+------------+------+-------+
```

**Spark-Sql**

Register both Dataframe as temp table then perform join using spark sql

```
scala> df1.registerTempTable("temp1")

scala> df2.registerTempTable("temp2")

scala> spark.sql("select a.company_id,a.city,a.updated_date,b.state,b.zipcode from temp1 a inner join temp2 as b on a.company_id = b.company_id  ").show

+----------+-----+------------+------+-------+
|company_id| city|updated_date| state|zipcode|
+----------+-----+------------+------+-------+
|       111|city1|  1990-12-01|state1| 111111|
|       222|city2|  1991-12-01|state2| 222222|
+----------+-----+------------+------+-------+
```

if you have any query related this please let me know. HAppy HAdoop

Comment: @BdLearner if its solve your purpose please accept answer aswell.

Comment: @BdLearner here I am using your code snippet with some modification.
var joinDs = df1.select("company_id","city","updated_date").join(df2.select("company_id","state","zipcode"),  df1("company_id").equalTo(df2("company_id")), "inner").drop(df1("company_id"))
please check and let me know if you again face any issue

Comment: @BdLearner huurrre